# Typescript - Dynamically object assign?

Tags: typescript, mobx-react

I am quite new to Typescript, and anything outside of JS to be honest.

I am wanting to create a single function similar to a JS function along the lines of

```
updateField(key, val) {
    this[key] = val
  }
```

I don't know if this is achievable in typescript. If this is something that should not be done and breaks the point of typescript, i guess i am happy to create multiple functions.

I have tried following other answers to similar questions but have hit a wall and am unsure of what else to try.. 
But this is where i ended up.    Note: i am using mobx, hence the use of 'this'

Even happy with a better education at to why this isn't achievable.

```
export class WhoForSelection {
  @persist @observable label = ''
  @persist @observable value = ''
}

class EQuiz {
  whoFor: WhoForSelection

  fistName: string
  dob: string
  gender: string

  @action
  updateField<T extends keyof EQuiz, K extends EQuiz[T]>(name: T, value: K) {
    this[name] = value
  }
}
```

with errors along the lines of

```
(parameter) name: T extends "whoFor" | "fistName" | "dob" | "gender" | "updateField"
Type 'K' is not assignable to type 'this[T]'.
  Type 'EQuiz[T]' is not assignable to type 'this[T]'.
    Type 'EQuiz' is not assignable to type 'this'.
      'EQuiz' is assignable to the constraint of type 'this', but 'this' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'EQuiz'.
        Type 'EQuiz[T]' is not assignable to type 'WhoForSelection &
```

Comment: what typescript version and compiler options do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that TypeScript thinks you want to update any of the properties of `EQuiz`, including `updateField`. `updateField` needs an access to `this` and it requires `this` to be of type `EQuiz`.

In this case TypeScript requires you to explicitly say that `updateField` needs a particular `this`:

```
// Notice the "this" as the first argument
updateField<T extends keyof EQuiz, K extends EQuiz[T]>(this: EQuiz, name: T, value: K) {
  this[name] = value;
}
```

You can read more about `this` types in [TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters)

Comment: Thanks, both your answers have helped and solved my issue.  I'll give that link a read.

Answer (score 1):

You are testing the type on the way in, so you can be dynamic within the method without risk.

```
class EQuiz {
  firstName: string = '';
  dob: string = '';
  gender: string = '';
  test: number = 0;

  updateField<T extends keyof EQuiz, K extends EQuiz[T]>(name: T, value: K) {
    this[name] = value as any;
  }
}

const quiz = new EQuiz();

quiz.updateField("firstName", "name");
quiz.updateField("test", 1);
```

Auto-completion tells you "firstName" needs to be given a string and "test" needs to be given a number. Given the "locked down" nature of this method signature, you'll need to decide whether it gives you a specific benefit over `quiz.firstName = "name"`.

If your intention is that the string becomes dynamic, you lose the type safety immediately as the compiler won't know if the dynamic string is a valid choice, or which one it is for type safety. Your signature then might as well be far simpler, and you might need to have the method check whether the key is valid instead.